# Batch-file that hides Powershell's progress bar at Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to make a batch script that hides Powershell's progress bar at `Invoke-WebRequest` command. I have already tried:

```bat
powershell.exe -command "$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'"
```

but it doesn't work. I can't add more information.

Here is my code:

```bat
powershell.exe -command "$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'"
powershell -command "INVOKE-WEBREQUEST http://download1502.mediafire.com/blahblah/blahblah2 -OUTFILE %TEMP%\Sibelius751209INStall100.tmp\AvidPF.zip"
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a *batch* file? Would it not be easier to run a Powershell script directly?

Comment: @Tomalak -> I need a batch file because I have a long batch code that I can't run with Powershell. And I also tried to make a separate file named `script.ps1`with that code. I placed it in Desktop. In my batch code I wrote `start C:\Users\admin\Desktop\script.ps1`, but the progress bar still appears.

Comment: What if you do `$global:progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'`? (shot in the dark..)

Comment: @Theo -> Still not works!

Comment: The problem is that you call two different Powershell processes. You must set the variable and run `Invoke-WebRequst` in a single go.

Comment: @Tomalak -> How can I do that? I am starter in batch and Powershell script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call powershell.exe two times. Any variables you set in the first call only exist in the first call. You must use a single call.

```
powershell.exe -command "$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest http://download1502.mediafire.com/blahblah/blahblah2 -OutFile '$Env:TEMP\Sibelius751209INStall100.tmp\AvidPF.zip'"
```

For better re-usablility I'd save a .ps1 file `download.ps1`:

```
$progressPreference = "silentlyContinue"

$url = $args[0]
$outfile = $args[1]

Invoke-WebRequest $url -Outfile $outfile
```

and call it from cmd.exe / from a batch file

```
set "URL=http://download1502.mediafire.com/blahblah/blahblah2"
set "OUTFILE=%TEMP%\Sibelius751209INStall100.tmp\AvidPF.zip"

powershell -File download.ps1 "%URL%" "%OUTFILE%"
```

Comment: I know `%TEMP%` in Powershell will go to C:\Windows\Temp path. `$Env:Temp` will go to %APPDATA%\Local\Temp path?

Comment: No, it won't. `%TEMP%` and `$Env:TEMP` refer to the same thing - the environment variable named "TEMP". And this value of this environment variable is the same for all processes you start. The former is cmd.exe syntax, the latter is powershell.exe syntax.

Comment: It says that `$Env:TEMP` drive doesn't exist. I placed it with `%APPDATA%\Local\Temp` and it works. Thank you for solving my problem! :D

Comment: Of course it depends on what TEMP is set to on your machine.